# JavaScript accessor property naming convention

Tags: javascript, properties, naming-conventions, naming

I come from a .NET background, and Microsoft seems to like having methods and properties that begin with uppercase letters. e.g. `PrintMessage();`

JavaScript seems to follow Java's rules for naming in that function names should begin with lowercase letters. e.g. `printMessage();`

JavaScript (ECMAScript version 5) now supports accessor properties, similar to properties in .NET. Again .NET likes to have properties beginning with uppercase letters. e.g. `Message`

So my question is, which naming convention should JavaScript use for properties?

e.g. `Message` or `message`?

I've already looked through some style guides, but I can't see much on the subject of properties.

Comment: I'm sure this is a very opinionated subject, but it is usual to start a constructor's name with a capital letter (and camelcase), otherwise start with a lower and use camelcase. (very general)

Comment: Hungarian notation, not a bad idea for loose typed languages, makes it a moot point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Douglas Crockford's](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) take on the subject.

> Names
>
> Names should be formed from the 26 upper and lower case letters (A .. Z, a .. z), the 10 digits (0 .. 9), and _ (underbar). Avoid use of international characters because they may not read well or be understood everywhere. Do not use $ (dollar sign) or \ (backslash) in names.
>
> Do not use _ (underbar) as the first character of a name. It is sometimes used to indicate privacy, but it does not actually provide privacy. If privacy is important, use the forms that provide private members. Avoid conventions that demonstrate a lack of competence.
>
> Most variables and functions should start with a lower case letter.
>
> Constructor functions which must be used with the new prefix should start with a capital letter. JavaScript issues neither a compile-time warning nor a run-time warning if a required new is omitted. Bad things can happen if new is not used, so the capitalization convention is the only defense we have.
>
> Global variables should be in all caps. (JavaScript does not have macros or constants, so there isn't much point in using all caps to signify features that JavaScript doesn't have.)

[W3C's](http://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Call_things_by_their_name_.E2.80.94_easy.2C_short_and_readable_variable_and_function_names) take on the subject

> Call things by their name — easy, short and readable variable and function names
>
> This is a no-brainer but it is scary how often you will come across variables like x1, fe2 or xbqne in JavaScript, or — on the other end of the spectrum — variable names like incrementorForMainLoopWhichSpansFromTenToTwenty or createNewMemberIfAgeOverTwentyOneAndMoonIsFull.
>
> None of these make much sense — good variable and function names should be easy to understand and tell you what is going on — not more and not less. One trap to avoid is marrying values and functionality in names. A function called isLegalDrinkingAge() makes more sense than isOverEighteen() as the legal drinking age varies from country to country, and there are other things than drinking to consider that are limited by age.
>
> Hungarian notation is a good variable naming scheme to adopt (there are other naming schemes to consider), the advantage being that you know what something is supposed to be and not just what it is.
>
> For example, if you have a variable called familyName and it is supposed to be a string, you would write it as sFamilyName in “Hungarian”. An object called member would be oMember and a Boolean called isLegal would be bIsLegal.It is very informative for some, but seems like extra overhead to others — it is really up to you whether you use it or not.
>
> Keeping to English is a good idea, too. Programming languages are in English, so why not keep this as a logical step for the rest of your code. Having spent some time debugging Korean and Slovenian code, I can assure you it is not much fun for a non-native speaker.
>
> See your code as a narrative. If you can read line by line and understand what is going on, well done. If you need to use a sketchpad to keep up with the flow of logic, then your code needs some work. Try reading Dostojewski if you want a comparison to the real world — I got lost on a page with 14 Russian names, 4 of which were pseudonyms. Don't write code like that — it might make it more art than product, but this is rarely a good thing.

[wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifier_naming_convention#JavaScript) take on the subject

> JavaScript
>
> The built-in JavaScript libraries use the same naming conventions as Java. Classes use upper camel case (RegExp, TypeError, XMLHttpRequest, DOMObject) and methods use lower camel case (getElementById, getElementsByTagNameNS, createCDATASection). In order to be consistent most JavaScript developers follow these conventions. See also: Douglas Crockford's conventions